# Trouble compiling Tensorflow in c++/Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, git, tensorflow

I have trouble getting Tensorflow to work in my c++ environment: Eclipse.
I git cloned tensorflow, built with bazel, and installed the resulting pip-package exactly like described here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources

I created a new c++ project in Eclipse and added the /home/tensorflow to the include paths. However, when I try to build a simple "hello world" project with a few includes from TF I run into this error:

```
23:05:39 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project cat_face ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -I/home/name/tensorflow -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src/cat_face.o ../src/cat_face.cpp 
In file included from ../src/cat_face.cpp:2:0:
/home/name/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/public/session.h:22:48: fatal error: tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h"
                                                ^
compilation terminated.

23:05:39 Build Finished (took 186ms)
```

It seems to look for a file, which doesn't exist in the Tensorflow directory. Why is it looking for something that doesn't exist? I checked it out and the file really isn't there, even though I followed all steps.

My program was very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "/tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!


}
```

Where could this have gone wrong?

Comment: I've never seen a #include with a leading slash, maybe try removing it (ie: `#include "tensorflow..."` rather than `#include "/tensorflow..."`)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it didn't change anyting.

Comment: Where're the library headers located? Where is your project location? You should specify a proper include path.

Comment: The library headers are in /home/name/tensorflow.

The project itself is placed in a shared folder. I'm using a virtual machine. I'll try and see if the project location is the problem, but I suspect not.

Could it be that I simply forgot something? I cloned, built and pip installed the package and included the include paths in the project folder before attempting compilation. Are more steps needed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to use [bazel](http://bazel.io) instead of cmake and make to build you project.
From what I know graph.pb.h is created by bazel during the build process.

Someone else had a similar problem: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1890